# Ext Tree, Data is displayed in console, but does not display on page

Tags: php, html, mysql, extjs, tree

My data is displayed in console, but does not display in ExtJs tree?

My php file

```
    $data = array();

    $sql = "";

    if (!isset($_POST['node'])) {
        // first select the top node that have no parent
        $sql = "SELECT id_no,value_data FROM extjs_tree WHERE parent IS NULL";
    } else {
        // select data with parent_id = $_POST['node']
        $sql = "SELECT id_no, value_data FROM extjs_tree WHERE parent = '". $_POST['node'] ."'";                                            
    }   

    $q = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        // check if have a child node                           
        $qq = mysql_query("SELECT id_no, value_data FROM extjs_tree WHERE parent = '". $r['id'] ."'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($qq) > 0) {
            // if have a child
            $r['leaf'] = false;
            $r['cls'] = 'folder';
        } else {
            // if have no child
            $r['leaf'] = true;
            $r['cls'] = 'file';
        }
        $data[] = $r;

    }               


    echo json_encode($data);
```

My JS file

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.tip.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            actionMethods:'post',
            url:'get-nodes.php'


        },
        root: {
            text: 'Root Node',
            id: 'root_node',
            expanded: true
        },
        folderSort: true,
        sorters: [{
            property:'text',
            direction:'ASC'
        }]
    });

    var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store: store,
        renderTo: 'tree_el',
        height: 300,
        width: 250,
        title: 'Products Display'
    });
});
```

I am getting the tree properly, I can see the data in the console. But I cannot see ExtJs displaying the values??

My present result

[image]

My expected result should be

[image]

Comment: sidenote: there is huge security hole at line `$sql = "SELECT id_no, value_data FROM extjs_tree WHERE parent = '". $_POST['node'] ."'";`. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You ned to change `value:` for `text:` or map your model differently since you're using the default NodeMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can also add following field to your store:

```
{
  name: 'text',
  mapping: 'value'
}
```

Comment: My store looks like this and its not working??

   `var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  proxy: {
   type:'ajax',
   actionMethods:'post',
   url:'get-nodes.php', 
   name: 'text',
   mapping: 'value'`

Comment: seems like you have added the name and mapping field to the proxy of the store instead as separate fields.
See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-fields

Answer (score 0):

Every item of response has to have `text` field in it. As I can see from your request-response images You don't send `text` field. Response should be looking like the following one:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Fruits", // this field is required
    ...
},
    ...
]
```

Comment: Is it required in the store?

Comment: @StrataGeeksCEO, No. In response json. Otherwise you have to modify your model as Thomas has noted.